# Can we use React Table from 'react-table' these days?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to creat a table by using the react-table. However, if I look at the docs of React Table, the "ReactTable" seems like already disappeared from docks.

What libraries are the easiest way to show API data into a table in React?

Comment: react-table has now provided useTables hook which can be used.

Comment: It was V6. Now, V7 has a hooks way of implementation, Follow docs.